# How to store the data from other class to an array?

Tags: java

```
    public class CompetitorFileReader {
    public String line;
    public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void Mary() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("competitors.txt"));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
            list.add(line);
    }
    public String Mary() throws IOException
    {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("competitors.txt")) ;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
           list.add(line);
    }

    String[] lineobjects = list.get(0).split(",");
    System.out.println("Competitor:"+lineobjects[0]);
    System.out.println("Competitor ID:"+lineobjects[1]);
    System.out.println("Competitor Event:"+lineobjects[2]);
    System.out.println("Performance:"+lineobjects[3]);

    return line;
    }
```

//

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] data = {CompetitorFileReader.Mary()};
    }
}
```

Can i do like this? i am just not know how to put the first class of Mary to the array of the main class.i change it now, is it correct?

Comment: You need an instance of `CompetitorFileReader` and your method should return that array to capture here

Comment: Mary is a method with void as return type, so you won't actually be getting any data. so, no, you can't do that. Also: what is "the first class of Mary" ?

Comment: the output of Mary(), i want to put it to the array in the other class.

Comment: @Sam change `void` to `String[]` and return `lineobjects`.

Comment: Perhaps you should review [a tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html). Note that you shouldn't name a method `Mary`. The name is supposed to start in lowercase, and be meaningful, like `readLinesAndSplitFirstLine`.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can,
just create a new instance of your class (`CompetitorFileReader`), call your method (`Mary`), then add your list data into your array (you should loop through them and add them one by one).

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       CompetitorFileReader competitor = new CompetitorFileReader();
       competitor.Mary();
       String [] data = new String[CompetitorFileReader.list];
       int i=0;
       for(String s : CompetitorFileReader.list){
          data[i++] = s;
      }
   }
```